# Color change when zoomed out large GeoTIFF (34gb from mosaic .ECW)

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, export

I have a large GeoTIFF (34gb, exported using ArcMap Copy Raster Tool). We had many troubles exporting the original .ECW mosaic map to a GeoTIFF with original resolution but a smaller extant.. Now the zoomed out map has a yellow coloured lower part of the map

[image: weird coloured large geotiff]

When zoomed in yellow hue disappears and only original colours are shown... But only at a scale of +/- 1:600. Is this a wrong export? Or is there a way to fix this?

Maybe I should ask the government contact for a new exported GeoTIFF. This person uses ArcMap, what would be the best way (tool?) to select an extant of a full .ecw mosaiced picture in original resolution?